# Web application to send SMS email

Tags: sms

Is there a web application that will let me send [SMS email](https://www.billmonk.com/about/sms)? Some services don't seem to support receiving normal email.

Comment: Do you mean an email to SMS gateway ?

Comment: SMS is completely different from email so please make your question clearer.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sms

Comment: @phwd, @citadelgrad: I hadn't heard of this before I saw this webpage; https://www.billmonk.com/about/sms

Comment: The title seems to ask "how can I send an SMS from a web app using a browser" which is a good question.  However, maybe that's not the question at all...

Comment: @Casebash, link down.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the cellular phone carrier can decide whether you can send SMS via email or not. Here's how to reach people on the most popular carriers:

> **T-Mobile**: phonenumber@tmomail.net
> **Virgin Mobile**: phonenumber@vmobl.com
> **Cingular**: phonenumber@cingularme.com
> **Sprint**: phonenumber@messaging.sprintpcs.com
> **Verizon**: phonenumber@vtext.com
> **Nextel**: phonenumber@messaging.nextel.com
>
> where phonenumber = your 10 digit phone number
>
> [Source](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/939/sms_email_cingular_nextel_sprint_tmobile_verizon_virgin/)

---

If you have some programming skills, you could make use of an SMS API (such as [ZeepMobile](http://www.zeepmobile.com/) or [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/sms/)) and build a database associating emails to an SMS phone number. Then you could send emails to "phonenumber@yourappname.com". The app would receive the email and redirect the message to the appropriate phone number.

Comment: if he meant this then you can use [Textie](http://textie.me/) on your iPhone

Comment: Sorry, the question wasn't the clearest. [This](https://www.billmonk.com/about/sms) is what I meant by SMS email

Comment: @Casebash, simply sending an email to that address doesn't work? Does the service reply with some kind of error message?

Comment: I'm not sure what happened, testing again

Comment: Actually it does seem to accept normal email, just really slow about it!

Comment: @mbillard, Are these "emails to SMS" free of charge?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using the email to SMS function most carriers provide for 3 reasons: (1) the email address seem to change over time (I've had mine change with my carrier a few times) and (2) some carriers charge to receive email to SMS messages and (3) it's annoying to read, since I know some of them require you to respond with "Read" or similar before seeing the who message.

I've been using [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/) for [voice](http://www.twilio.com/how-twilio-works) and I've been quite impressed. I'm sure their [SMS](http://www.twilio.com/sms/) system isn't much different. You also wouldn't need to have much programming knowledge, although it would be a good idea to provide security.

There is also a similar quesiton on [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/533/how-to-add-sms-text-messaging-functionality-to-my-website).

Comment: But twilio is considered expensive isn't it?

Comment: I would consider $0.0075 per message to be fairly cheap (https://www.twilio.com/sms/pricing) although there are probably cheaper ones out there, but being that it's so easy to setup I'd say it probably saves that amount of $$.

Comment: Hmm, considering the charge is *per* SMS, that's actually pretty expensive. If you send 20k SMSes per day, that's already costing ~$5k per month.

Comment: And there are cheaper options? 20k is a lot of messages!

Comment: A normal client subscription plan would give 1k free SMSes for a mere $30 per month, costing us just $600 for 20k (10x cheaper than $5k)...

Comment: ...okay, so where would one find this service?

Comment: I'm talking about the plans provided by telephone providers...

Comment: Just did a bit of research and you're probably right that you can get cheaper rates through regular phone providers, but the ones I checked had far less features than Twilio, the API & admin interface were less easy to use and their APIs are not as well documented. Also, their pricing isn't clear (ie, does a regular phone plan give you access to the API?). The other thing that Twilio is good for is international text messages, especially because they're much cheaper (here (Canada), prices can be around $0.75/msg for international vs <$0.04/msg at Twilio).