# Email address which forwards to my Google Voice SMS inbox

Tags: email, google-voice, sms

**NOTE**:
*This question intentionally replicates
[What SMS email address works for Google Voice?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17904/what-sms-email-address-works-for-google-voice)
But that is 8+ years old, and the accepted answer does not apply.
I guess it would be misleading to place a bounty on that question, users will not understand the "history" of the post.*

I have a Google Voice number XXX-XXX-XXXX.
**How can I "build" an email address such that email sent to it show up in my SMS inbox for XXX-XXX-XXXX?**

For other companies, it used to be something like posted 10 years ago:

[Web application to send SMS email](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4955/web-application-to-send-sms-email)

Related:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Googlevoice/comments/8f8eav/will_gv_ever_have_an_emailtosms_gateway/

https://www.howardforums.com/showthread.php/1901954-Google-voice-sms-gateway